# Combining labeled and unlabeled data in a single pipeline

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, dbn

I'm building image classifier that uses [**DBN**](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Deep_belief_networks) for feature learning and **logistic regression** to fine-tune resulting network. Normally, the most convenient way to implement such an architecture in SciKit Learn is to use [**Pipeline**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) class. But in my case I have ~10K unlabeled images and only ~300 labeled ones. Surely, I want to use *all* images to train DBN and fit logistic regression with *only labeled* examples.

I can think of implementing my own Pipeline class that will handle this case, but first I'd like to know if there's already something existing. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current scikit-learn Pipeline API is not well suited for supervised learning with unsupervised pre-training. Implementing your own wrapper class is probably the best way to go forward for that case.